# Python cron job failing

Tags: python, cron

I have a cron job that is set up and ready to go. My file looks like this:

```
    import sys,os
    input = sys.argv[1]
    if os.path.isfile(input)==False:
        print("Ensure input csv file exists")
        quit()
    # do stuff
    print("Continued")
```

When I run the command `python3 /home/abc/data_a.py /home/abc/data_b.csv` on the linux terminal, the program continues as expected.

However, when I schedule it as a cronjob using `0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * python3 /home/abc/data_a.py /home/abc/data_b.csv` then the output "Ensure input csv file exists" gets printed and the program exits itself. What's going on?

Comment: It seems that the cron is not handeling the program properly. Did you modified the code slightly when assigning cron jobs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like my crontab command wasn't run properly (where initially I manually created a `crontab.txt` file and ran the command `crontab crontab.txt`.

Solved it by:

1) `crontab -r` to revert

2) using `crontab -e` and editing the crontab file inside with the same arguments

Answer (score -1):

**quit()** It is terminates a Python script. So once the quit() call. The next line will not execute.

Comment: quit is called only if input file does not exist. Statement is correct.

Comment: yes, but **python3** is not consider as a sys **argument**. "command" is first arg and file is second arg. so if you print the sys.argv in the script. It will show only [command, file] not python3.